# strcpy Gives Segmentation fault

Tags: c, recursion, strcpy

The following is a recursive function that is supposed to turn an integer into a string

```
char* int_to_word(int word_int){
    static char new[2];
    char alphabet[26]={"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"};
    new[0]=alphabet[word_int%27-1];
    //new[1]='\0';
    if(word_int/27==0){
        return new;
    }
    static char *word;
    strcpy(word,strcat(int_to_word(word_int/27),new));
    return word;
}
```

I'm getting a segmentation fault with the line `strcpy(word,strcat(int_to_word(word_int/27),new));` when `word_int` > 26. To my knowledge, there's no reason it shouldn't work. My best guess is that I somehow neeed to allocate `word` before copying into it, but changing the initializer to `static char *word=(*char)malloc(100)` did not help.

Comment: What memory is `*word` pointing to?

Comment: You never initialized `word`, you need to use `malloc()` to allocate memory for it.

Comment: Using static variables with a recursive function isn't going to work. You'll end up trying to copy between the same strings.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to get around the fact that you can't return a local array, by using static variables instead. But that causes a new problem: Every time you call the function, you'll overwrite the array that you returned from a different call.

Comment: This `char alphabet[26]={"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"};` is not what you want, is an `**char` you probably want `char foo[] = "bar";`

Comment: Maybe `%  26`???????

Comment: You return `word`, which is a pointer to char defined in the previous line but not initialised and not malloced for. Then you ask strcpy to write to the memory referenced by that non-initialised pointer. Be grateful for your nice computer to help you with a segfault. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy